# Verify my proof: if $A \Delta B \subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm self studying from this book "How to Prove it" by Velleman (3rd edition). I don't have access to a math professor, so I need a little help from the community. Please verify my proof.

Exercise 6 pag. 150

> The symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ is the set $A \Delta B$ = $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \cup B) \setminus (B \cap A)$. Prove that if $A \Delta B \subseteq A$ then $B \subseteq A$.

**Proof**. Let's note $A \Delta B \subseteq A$ as (1). In order to satisfy (1), an element $x$ must be a member of both $A$ and $B$. Now (1) can be rewritten as  : $\forall x(x \in B\ and\ x \in A \implies x \in A)$ or
$\forall x(x \notin A \implies x \notin B\ or\ x \notin A)$ (2)

Next, (2) can be rewritten as

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix} 
   \forall x(x \notin A \implies x \notin B) (3) \\
   \forall x(x \notin A \implies x \notin A) (4)
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Evidently we can drop (4), and (3) can be rewritten as $\forall x(x \in B \implies x \in A)$ $\blacksquare $

Comment: $\forall x(x \in B \wedge x \in A \Rightarrow x \in A)$ would actually be equivalent to $A \cap B \subseteq A,$ not $A \Delta B \subseteq A.$ The actual statement you would want is a bit more complicated, to the point where I would actually recommend a different approach: a proof by contradiction actually works very nicely here. (also, your "dropping" logic is a bit suspect)

Comment: Those who downvote the question, please also comment your decision.

Comment: "In order to satisfy (1), an element $x$ must be a member of both $A$ and $B$." This is a non-sequitur and false statement. In order for (1) to hold, what you need is that if $x\in A\triangle B$, then $x\in A$. That does not mean "an element $x$ must be a member of both $A$ and $B$." Since your first sentence already contains an erroneous assertion, the rest of the argument is irrelevant and incorrect.

Comment: Note that $A\Delta B\subseteq A$ implies $B\setminus A \subseteq A$. What does that tell us about the elements of $B\setminus A$?

Comment: The first two sentences of your proof should be "Assume that $A \bigtriangleup B \subseteq A$.  Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $B$."  You shouldn't be wasting time and effort thinking about why the theorem is true until you have written those two sentences.  Once you have written those sentences, you see that you don't need to think about, in general, what's in the various sets in the problem.  You just have to think about the one element $x$.  Now you have to prove $x \in A$.